# How to separate UITableView from data parsed from the Internet?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xml-parsing

I have an `UITableView` that is populated with parsed XML elements from the Internet.

All is working fine, but I'd like to separate the code to parse the XLM elements from the `UIViewController` that is responsible to populate this `UITableView`.

I've tried sublassing the `UIViewController`, but it seems to cause many coupling problems.

What's the best way to separate this XML asynchronous parser code, and then feed its results to the `UIViewController` that contains the `UITableView`?

I don't understand much of delegates, but is this the way to go?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an object that handles the parsing, create an instance of it in your view controller, and then call it to load up the data:

```
@protocol SomeXMLParserHandler <NSObject>

- (void) handleData:(NSArray *)data;

@end

@interface SomeXMLParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id<SomeXMLParserHandler> handler;

- (void) parseSomeXMLFromURL:(NSString *)url
            andPassToHandler:(id<SomeXMLParserHandler>)handler;

@end
```

In this example, **SomeXMLParser** would do all the heavy lifting and pass an array back to **SomeXMLParserHandler** when it's done.  So in your view controller you could do something similar to this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SomeXMLParser *parser = [[SomeXMLParser alloc] init];

    [parser parseSomeXMLFromURL:@"http://someurl"
               andPassToHandler:self];
}

- (void) handleData:(NSArray *)data
{
    self.tableViewData = data;
}
```

This isn't working code but it should get you going in the right direction, especially if you already have the parsing code working.  Also, if your into Blocks... you could swap out the protocol with a Block reference to do the work once parsing has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Your model should handle the fetching and parsing of the data, then when it's done u can use NSNotificationCenter to notify your view controller about the new data.
For example you can do as follow:

In your model define some `MyModelDidFinishFetchingDataNotification` and call it when u finished fetching and parsing the data

Then when u create your viewController add it as an observer to your model notification

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleMyModelDidFinishFetchingDataNotification:)
                                                     name:MyModelDidFinishFetchingDataNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In viewDidLoad tell your model to fetch the data

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.myModel fetchNewDataFromServer];
}
```

implement the method to handle the new data

```
- (void)handleMyModelDidFinishFetchingDataNotification:(NSNotification *)not
{
    NSArray *newData = [[not userInfo] objectForKey:@"someNewData"];

    // set the new data to the viewController data property
    self.myData = newData

    // update the UI
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```